# Goutte PHP does not submit form without submit input

Tags: php, forms, goutte, domcrawler

I have a form without a submit input:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php?step=UpdateReport" name="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="level" value ="UpdateReport">
<input type="image" source="xxxx" name="orderFree">
</form>
```

The form submits to itself.  When I call from my script

```
$form = $crawler->filter('form')->form();
$crawler = $client->submit($form);
echo $crawler->html();
```

I get the same form again.  If I dump the $form object I get only one input.
Any ideas how I can get this form to submit? Thank you all in advance

Comment: I have the same issue